# Can't find Next Button control in Wizard

Tags: asp.net, wizard

I am trying to use the FindControls method to find the Next Button in my Wizard so I can set it as the default button, but I can't seem to find it.

Here is the control name from View Source in IE:

```
ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_ApplicationWizard_StartNavigationTemplateContainerID_StartNextButton
```

This is the code block I'm using to set the default button:

```
Page.Form.DefaultButton = ApplicationWizard.FindControl("StartNavigationTemplateContainerID").FindControl("StartNextButton").UniqueID;
```

However, it can't find the StartNavigationTemplateContainerID control.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If there's anything that illustrates better the folly of the ASP.NET old, bad model of rendering stuff for you than the Wizard (lack of) Control, I don't know what it would be. Sorry, just felt like ranting.

Answer (score 1):

I was having trouble finding the next button on my wizard, but I found it this way:

Button btnNext = (Button)MyWizard.FindControl("StartNavigationTemplateContainerID$StartNextButton");

I found [this blog](http://romsteady.blogspot.com/2007/08/howto-find-controls-in-wizard.html) helpful.

Comment: This magical pass phrase turned out to be the winner. Note that the actual item's name, as displayed in firebug, was incorrect: `ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$EnrollmentWizard1$StartNavigationTemplateContainerID$StartNextButton`. So `StartNavigationTemplateContainerID$StartNextButton` is the phrase that pays, don't forget it kiddos.